# User defined filter for pandas dataframe

Tags: numpy, pandas, filtering, logical-operators, sympy

Iam writing an Qt based application showing tabular data. The app uses pandas dataframes to store the information. The user should be able to filter the dataframes, e.x.:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
   'elevation': [10, 20, 15, 12, 100, 150, 200, 200],        
   'name': ['tree', 'tree', 'house', 'tree', 'house']
})
df[(elevation > 10) & (elevation < 200)]
df[(elevation > 10) & (elevation < 200) & (name == 'tree')]
```

How could I construct such filter functions from a text input?
I tried to use SymPy to convert the function from the text input and to lambdify it later.

```
expr = sympify("(x > 10) & (x < 200)")
f = lambdify(x, expr, "numpy")
f(df)
```

If I use the dataframe as input I got the error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()".
If I use it with df.any() i got a true or false back, but no index series...
For simple x > 10 expressions it's working like expected, or better said, as wanted.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You must have an `elevation` variable present in your namespace, otherwise your code above wouldn't work. The filters need to be `df[(df["elevation"] > 10) & (df["elevation"] < 200) & (df["name"] == "tree")]`.

Comment: On a website the typical thing to do would be to present a form where the user can choose the column, a comparison operator and a value, as well as the possibility to chain filters using `&` or `|`. Could you adjust your QT app to do the same?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to adjust the gui.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you might be able to leverage [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-query):

```
>>> df.query("(elevation > 10) & (elevation < 200)")
   elevation   name
1         20   tree
2         15  house
3         12   tree
4        100  house
5        150   tree
>>> df.query("(elevation > 10) & (elevation < 200) & (name == 'tree')")
   elevation  name
1         20  tree
3         12  tree
5        150  tree
```

`query` can't handle everything, but it can handle stuff this simple.  If you need something more sophisticated, you could use `exec` or `eval` to construct functions on the fly; there are obvious security hazards there, but you'd have the same issues using `sympy` (it uses `eval` too.)

Alternatively, you could simply implement your own parser for what you need.

Comment: I didn't know, that it is so simple to write a parser with python for this problem. I think this will be the best solution for the moment. :) Thanks!